# Identify these connectors

Tags: identification, connector

I'm trying to identify (part number, etc.) these connectors.  The larger has 12 pins (pitch is 2.5 mm); the small has 13 pins (1.5mm).

[image: 12/13 pin connectors]

Comment: When possible, please provide the pin pitch (center-to-center pin spacing). Including a ruler in the image is okay, but not as good as measuring with calipers and providing that information.

Comment: Pitch: Left =~ 2.5 mm; right =~ 1.5 mm.

Comment: Thank you, everyone!

Comment: Also just a minor note Joe, you don't need to add "updated" to the title if you edit new information into the question. The idea is that the question will stand over time and be (potentially) useful to future users searching for the same info.

Answer (score 4):

Left: [Industry standard rectangular plug, 2.5 mm pitch made by multiple companies](https://connectorbook.com/identification.html?m=NN&n=lo_prof_1r_w2b_conn_2p5&&fl=0000000000000000000000000000000000000000002000100000-40c-%7C%7C%7C%7C%7C) (my site):

- MANUF. - SERIES
- [JST](https://www.jst-mfg.com/product/detail_e.php?series=58) - [EH](https://www.jst-mfg.com/product/pdf/eng/eEH.pdf) (pdf) - [digikey](https://www.digikey.com/short/9r00f2b1)
- [TE](https://www.te.com/usa-en/products/connectors/pcb-connectors/wire-to-board-connectors/intersection/high-performance-interconnects.html?tab=pgp-story) - [HPI-2.5 (3w)](https://www.te.com/commerce/DocumentDelivery/DDEController?Action=srchrtrv&DocNm=1-1773713-2_HPI_QRG_EN&DocType=DS&DocLang=EN) (pdf) - [digikey](https://www.digikey.com/short/jz0m1dd0)
- [TE](https://www.te.com/usa-en/products/connectors/pcb-connectors/wire-to-board-connectors/intersection/high-performance-interconnects.html?tab=pgp-story) - [HPI-2.5 (4w)](https://www.te.com/commerce/DocumentDelivery/DDEController?Action=srchrtrv&DocNm=1-1773713-2_HPI_QRG_EN&DocType=DS&DocLang=EN) (pdf) - [digikey](https://www.digikey.com/short/df8fj14p)
- [Wurth](https://www.we-online.com/catalog/en/em/connectors/wire-to-board/wr_wtb/wr_wtb_2_50_j_type) - WR-WTB 688

---

Right: [Industry standard rectangular plug, 1.5 mm pitch made by multiple companies](https://connectorbook.com/identification.html?m=NN&n=lo_prof_1r_w2b_conn_1p5&&fl=0000000000000000000000000000000000000000002000100000-40c-%7C%7C%7C%7C%7C) (my site):

- MANUF. - SERIES
- Adam tech - [15SH + 15CH](https://www.mouser.com/datasheet/2/4/page_234-240-12264.pdf) (pdf) - [digikey](https://www.digikey.com/short/zw10qr)
- [JST](https://www.jst-mfg.com/product/detail_e.php?series=287) - [ZH](http://www.jst-mfg.com/product/pdf/eng/eZH.pdf) (pdf) - [digikey](https://www.digikey.com/short/rh7hf0cn)
- [Wurth](https://www.we-online.com/catalog/en/em/connectors/wire-to-board/wr_wtb/wr_wtb_1_50_mm) - WR-WTB 648 - [digikey](https://www.digikey.com/short/34mjt74p)

Answer (score 3):

The bigger one looks like a JST EH connector, if the pin pitch is 2.5 mm like it appears to be.

The smaller one is probably also a JST connector, but from just the ruler in the image I can't tell what the pitch is, and without that I can't tell what series it is. Measure the pin pitch with calipers and edit that into the question, then let me know that you've done so and I'll update this.